# getting database results using string matching in my laravel app

Tags: php, laravel

I want the rows of a table which have some string `'str'` present in a particular column's value.

For ex.- I want all the rows of `'User'` table where `'user_name'` is `'halku'`.

I know about `str_contains()` and `where()`, but I want to know how to use them together.

I couldn't find any docs for something like that.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In databases this is called a `WHERE LIKE` statement.

In Laravel you use it like this:

```
$name = Input::get('name');
$users = User::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$name%")->get();
```

`%` is a wildcard. It means get all rows where column `name` has the word `$name` and there may be other text before or after that word.